# change angular ui-view inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I am using multiple named ui-views in a single controller. Everything is working as spected when name the ui-view in the html file with this code:

```
<div class="box"> 
  <div ui-view="selector"></div>  

  <div ui-view="widget1"></div>
  <div ui-view="widget2"></div>
  <div ui-view="widget3"></div>
  <div ui-view="widget4"></div>
</div>
```

But when I want to load dynamically some of those views with a ng-repeat it does not update the information.

```
<div class="widgets">
  <div class="widget-container" ng-repeat="widget in widgets">
    <div ui-view="{{widget}}"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How could I load ui-views from my ng-repeat?

Comment: I believe you should not use squiggly brackets: `<div ui-view="widget"></div>` vs `<div ui-view="{{widget}}"></div>`

Comment: You are right but it still don't change dynamicly. Finally i did it with ng-include and ng-controller. But thinks for the tip!! :)

Comment: Could you explain how you did this?

Answer (score 0):

This hadn't been answered so i decided to go ahead and show how to do it. Unfortunately for some reason the attempt in the question didn't work but what you can do is link to a function between curly brackets and return the string of the view you want. For instance the controller would look like this:

`$scope.groups = ['main','cases', 'models'];
 $scope.pickView = function(index){
     return $scope.groups[index];
 };`