# ui-router ng-repeat with dynamic named views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I wanting to dynamically load views into an accordion with ui-router. The thing is, when I generate the views by name inside ng-repeat I can't load the views at all.

I know that someone else asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305805/change-angular-ui-view-inside-ng-repeat) here but there's not solution to it.

Is this possible at all?

```
 <div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-repeat="group in groups">
   <div data-ui-view="step{{ group.number }}"></div>
 </div>
```

Edit:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/index1/id");//

    $stateProvider

        .state("index1", {
            abstract:true,
            url: "/index1",
            template: "<h1>This is index 1 abstract</h1><div ui-view></div>"
        })
        .state("index1.id", {
            url: "/id",
            template: "<h1>This is index1.id</h1>",
            controller: function($scope,$state){


            }
        })
        .state("index2", {
            abstract:true,
            url: "/index2",
            template: "<h1>This is index 2</h1><div ui-view></div>"
        })
        .state("index2.id", {
            url: "/id",
            template: "<h1>This is index 2.id</h1>" ,
            controller: function($scope,$state){


            }
        });
})
```

Edit: I've created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bullrout/4ZeXa/7/).I tried to load a named view after the repeater had finished but it just would not work. I just need a little help to get me started on this.

Comment: Yes it's possible. Can you show your $stateProvider setup?

Comment: Hi @tasseKATT, I've posted my provider. My accordion is reasonably small at around < 10 rows. I'm hoping that this will be possible.

Comment: Which states are you expecting to show in '<div data-ui-view="step{{ group.number }}"></div>'? Just trying to get the full picture.

Comment: I need to show both the abstract state's template and the child state. In other words I have the repeater generate the accordion sections and then I'd like to load the view into each accordion. when the accordion is expanded. Should I create a fiddle for this? Would that help at all?

Comment: @tasseKATT I've created a fiddle with the repeater and accordion, named views etc. I'm hoping that it's relatively easy to get this to work.

Comment: @tasseKATT are you able to help with this?

Comment: I will take a look later when I have time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit confused looking at your fiddle. Can you use this as a starting point and let me know what issues you run into? http://plnkr.co/edit/uPPAUFIZfSQbKrrFsTmI?p=preview

Comment: @Jimi Help me understand what you want to achieve in here. From my understanding, just remove the "step{{group.number}}" then the ui-router will load as expected. From my experience, if you set any attribute value to ui-router like ui-router="..." (even if the ... is the state name), the ui-router will not load. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Answer (score 1):

ui-router didn't support interpolated ui-view names until now: https://github.com/christopherthielen/ui-router/commit/81f6a19a432dac9198fd33243855bfd3b4fea8c0

It's not built into a release yet, but you can download the source and build it.

Comment: It is in there now, and can be used. It doesn't seem to work for <ion-nav-view>, it does for <ui-view>.